# How to format output from Maven Surefire report plugin

Tags: maven-surefire-plugin

I want to customize the output generated by Surefire report plugin.

It gives too many information and I'd like to have only two information

- the test name
- the execution time it has taken to complete the test.

Could anyone please help me to do that?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.12.4</version>
  <configuration>
      <outputName>YourTestName-${maven.build.timestamp}</outputName>
  </configuration>    
</plugin>
```

Hope this helped